# Ionic With Facebook connect on Android Device - probleme return url?

Tags: android, angularjs, facebook, frameworks, ionic-framework

I've general question with location for "ionic framework" -> lastest version installed..( CLI v 1.3.0)

for testing app with ionic serve and chrome : no probleme, we can get full path url
(principally for return url with services ""openfb.js"" per examples)
//////////

```
context = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2)),

baseURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + context,
```

OR :

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```

//////
BUT with ionic run android, i have popup theses informations of my path url or location on android (debug)..
result is : 
      file://android_asset/www/index.html#/app/messages (for my general location in page messages)

BUT return url for services fbconnect is calculated with context : " file://android_asset/ "

and facebook connect in this case get error : 
      " uri must be absolute" .. or... if i force location for my url to: "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" ( : 8100 with or not infos port is also testing )

i always get an error with " uri must be absolute" or connection refused with error popup and force close app... 
i've no solution for this.. all other function of my app with api server connection is ok...

thank for help me to resolve openfb probleme on android device (i think same probleme for ios)...

Oby.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have replace your openFb file with this [repository oepenfb file.](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB)

And also you have to add one plugin 'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser'.

In facebook OAuth redirect add this "http://localhost/oauthcallback.html"

Comment: Not functionnaly, sorry : plobleme is the same... perhaps native cordova plugin ?